# KnockoutJS - Work with a map of key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need to use a java.util.Map within Knockout JS. The `key` of the Map entry is always the path/name of a form-input; the `value` is the error message, which should be displayed next to the form-input:

E.g: `MyObject.getErrors().push("myObjects[0].myField1"), "This field is mandatory!");`

How can I check within Knockout JS, whether the Map key is equal to a inputs name, and if so, append a "error `<span>`" to the form input?

Is something even possible?

**JavaObject:**

```
public class MyObject {
    public String myField1;
    public String myField2;
    private Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

**Knockout Object:**

```
function MyObject(data) {
    this.field1 = ko.observable(data.field1);
    this.field1 = ko.observable(data.field1);
    this.errors = [{
        ?
    }]
}
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
    "class": "MyObjectHelper",
    "myObjects": [
        {
            "class": "MyObject",
            "errors": {

            },
            "field1": "ABC123",
            "field2": "01.01"
        },
        {
            "class": "com.itensis.leina16.application.data.domain.Configuration",
            "errors": {
                "myObjects[1].field2": "Is required"
            },
            "field1": "ASDF123",
            "field2": ""
        },
        {
            "class": "com.itensis.leina16.application.data.domain.Configuration",
            "errors": {
                "configurations[2].field1": "Is required",
                "configurations[2].field2": "Is required"
            },
            "field1": "",
            "field2": ""
        }
    ],
    "hasErrors": true
}
```

Comment: It depends on how the Java JSON serializer you use works. Most likely it serializes `HashMap` into a plain JS object (`{key: value, otherKey: otherValue}'). Try and `console.log(data)` and show us how `data.errors` looks like. If it's an object then you can simply use `obj.errors.key` and `obj.errors.otherKey`.

Comment: The serialized Java Object looks like: `"field1": "ABC123","field2":"XYZ789","errors":{"myObjects[0].myField1":"IS required"}`. Each entry/message in the map is related to one field of the current MyObject. So while loop over all MyObject's, I want to check whether a error message is avaible for the field.

Comment: I added the formatted JSON response. It seems that this response cannot be parsed with `JSON.parse(response)`, because field `errors` is not available in parsed object. Just all the other fields(1,2,..)